# How to make Nginx redirect without adding a tail string to redirected server

Tags: nginx, iis, redirect

I have an Nginx that redirects to several different web servers based on URL path after host.

My Nginx host is **nginx.main.com**

current redirect rules are

```
 # Redirects for Math     
     location ~ ^/(math)($|/) {
     proxy_pass  http://www.aaa.com:8081;
     include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
     break;   }

  # Redirects for CS  
     location ~ ^/(cs)($|/) {
     proxy_pass  http://www.aaa.com:8082;
     include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
     break;   }
```

This causes

> http://nginx.main.com/math/index.html to be redirected to
>   http://www.aaa.com:8081/math/index.html

And

> http://nginx.main.com/cs/index.html to be redirected to
>   http://www.aaa.com:8082/cs/index.html

(My 2 aaa sites sit on IIS on two different ports and 2 different base dirs)

Because of IIS restrictions *I dont want the '/math/' and '/cs/' to be added to the destination URL*.

e.g., I want

```
http://nginx.main.com/math/index.htm to be redirected to http://www.aaa.com:8081/index.html
```

Is this possible with Nginx ?

Comment: Do you misuse word *redirect* instead of *(reverse) proxy*?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, if I understand you question correctly

```
location /math/ {
    proxy_pass  http://www.aaa.com:8081/;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
}

location /cs/ {
    proxy_pass  http://www.aaa.com:8082/;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
}
```

I see no reason to use regexp `location`s, so I changed them to simple. Also `break` directive does nothing in this config.

I've added trailing slash to `proxy_pass` so nginx replaces location prefix with this slash and result is `http://nginx.main.com/cs/index.html` proxied to `http://www.aaa.com:8082/index.html`.

Comment: This didn't work, it still passes the /cs or /math to the destination web server. I found that using "rewrite   ^/math(.*)$ $1 break;" will do the trick though !

Comment: One more problem that arose after using rewrite... Any root resource that is accessed from the destination site (e.g., /scripts/foo.js) ruins the whole proxy scheme here because it will try to access nginx.main.com/scripts.foo.js which obviously does not exist. So the only solution left is to use vhosts with their own DNS (e.g., math.main.com and cs.main.com) :P